# Unable to import json file into spyder

Tags: json, directory, path, load

This is my first time using any sort of code. I have been following along with an interactive tutorial and I seem to be stuck at the very first step, trying to import a json file containing info regarding football competition data. It seems fairly straightforward but error message after error message has started to drive me insane.

I am trying to load the data into python in order to follow along with a tutorial (I will leave a link below). I believe I have saved my files and data in the same way as in the tutorial but when I change the file directory and run: import json I get a few different error messages if  someone could advise on what I’m doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to load in the data which I have downloaded from GitHub and open the competitions JSON file.

I am also happy to provide any information required to help answer this question.

YouTube video:https://youtu.be/GTtu0t03FMO

error messages:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Statsbomb/data/competitions.json'

JSONDecodeError:Expecting value 

#Load in Statsbomb competition and match data
#This is a library for loading json files.
import json
#Load the competition file
#Got this by searching 'how do I open json in Python'
with open('Statsbomb/data/competitions.json') as f:
    competitions = json.load(f)

#Womens World Cup 2019 has competition ID 72
competition_id=72

#Womens World Cup 2019 has competition ID 72
competition_id=72


#Load the list of matches for this competition
with open('Statsbomb/data/matches/'+str(competition_id)+'/30.json') as f:
    matches = json.load(f)

#Look inside matches
matches[0]
matches[0]['home_team']
matches[0]['home_team']['home_team_name']
matches[0]['away_team']['away_team_name']

#Print all match results
for match in matches:
    home_team_name=match['home_team']['home_team_name']
    away_team_name=match['away_team']['away_team_name']
    home_score=match['home_score']
    away_score=match['away_score']
    describe_text = 'The match between ' + home_team_name + ' and ' + away_team_name
    result_text = ' finished ' + str(home_score) +  ' : ' + str(away_score)
    print(describe_text + result_text)

#Now lets find a match we are interested in
home_team_required ="England"
away_team_required ="Sweden"

#Find ID for the match
for match in matches:
    home_team_name=match['home_team']['home_team_name']
    away_team_name=match['away_team']['away_team_name']
    if (home_team_name==home_team_required) and (away_team_name==away_team_required):
        match_id_required = match['match_id']
print(home_team_required + ' vs ' + away_team_required + ' has id:' + str(match_id_required))

#Exercise: 
#1, Edit the code above to print out the result list for the Mens World cup 
#2, Edit the code above to find the ID for England vs. Sweden
#3, Write new code to write out a list of just Sweden's results in the tournament.
```

Comment: the error is self explanitory `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Statsbomb/data/competitions.json'` So I'd double check your path in `with open('Statsbomb/data/competitions.json') as f:`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, so if I can view all the files in my file explorer. Should I include the  absolute file path to try and fix this ?

Comment: Won’t be the most robust, but should do the trick for you.

Comment: When I change to the absolute file path I get the error: JSONDecodeError: expecting value

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate it I’ve sent an email across.

Answer (score 0):

with open('Statsbomb/data/matches/'+str(competition_id)+'/30.json') as f:
matches = json.load(f)
try:
with open('Statsbomb/data/matches/'+str(competition_id)+'/3.json') as f:
matches = json.load(f)

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)